# How update row with inner joins

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I have this select statement where I found two rows, and I want to update a specific column:

```
select * from murex.STPDLV_ENTRY_TABLE a 
inner join (select DLV_FLOW_XX, max(TS_TIME_LONG) AS MaxDateTime from murex.STPDLV_ENTRY_TABLE group by DLV_FLOW_XX) b 
on a.DLV_FLOW_XX = b.DLV_FLOW_XX
and a.TS_TIME_LONG=b.MaxDateTime
and a.DLV_FLOW_XX in (3741539,4044126,3741551)
and a.STP_UDF9 !='Posted';
```

I have tried:

```
update STPDLV_ENTRY_TABLE a
set a.STP_UDF9 = 'Posted'
where
inner join (select DLV_FLOW_XX, max(TS_TIME_LONG) AS MaxDateTime from murex.STPDLV_ENTRY_TABLE group by DLV_FLOW_XX) b 
on a.DLV_FLOW_XX = b.DLV_FLOW_XX
and a.TS_TIME_LONG=b.MaxDateTime
and a.DLV_FLOW_XX in (3741539,4044126,3741551);
```

How do I correctly construct the update query?

SOLUTION:

```
update (select * 
        from STPDLV_ENTRY_TABLE a 
        inner join (select DLV_FLOW_XX
                           , max(TS_TIME_LONG) AS MaxDateTime 
                    from STPDLV_ENTRY_TABLE 
                    group by DLV_FLOW_XX) b 
        on a.DLV_FLOW_XX = b.DLV_FLOW_XX
        and a.TS_TIME_LONG = b.MaxDateTime
        and a.DLV_FLOW_XX in (3741539,4044126,3741551)
        and a.STP_UDF9 !='Posted') test
set test.STP_UDF9 = 'Posted';
```

Comment: *What* do you want to update?

Comment: sorry i have edited the script

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+join+sql-update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your query as a table:

```
update (select * 
        from STPDLV_ENTRY_TABLE a 
        inner join (select DLV_FLOW_XX
                           , max(TS_TIME_LONG) AS MaxDateTime 
                    from STPDLV_ENTRY_TABLE 
                    group by DLV_FLOW_XX) b 
        on a.DLV_FLOW_XX = b.DLV_FLOW_XX
        and a.TS_TIME_LONG = b.MaxDateTime
        and a.DLV_FLOW_XX in (3741539,4044126,3741551)
        and a.STP_UDF9 !='Posted') test
set test.STP_UDF9 = 'Posted';
```

Here is a demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=05c3496eebc90d02bd16decd0d1b4772)

Answer (score 0):

To me, `merge` looks like a better/simpler choice.

```
MERGE INTO stpdlv_entry_table a
     USING (  SELECT dlv_flow_xx, MAX (ts_time_long) AS maxdatetime
                FROM murex.stpdlv_entry_table
            GROUP BY dlv_flow_xx) b
        ON (    a.dlv_flow_xx = b.dlv_flow_xx
            AND a.ts_time_long = b.maxdatetime)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET a.stp_udf9 = 'Posted'
           WHERE a.dlv_flow_xx IN (3741539, 4044126, 3741551);
```